# Printing grids and charts using flex printjob

Tags: apache-flex, printing, anychart

i have a dashboard which consists of advanced datagrids and anychart charts. My print function seems to print only the datagrids and not the charts. Please see code below.

```
public function PrintDashboard():void{
printJob = new FlexPrintJob(); // calls the dialog

if(printJob.start())  // Starts when the user presses ok
{

    printJob.addObject(dashPreview,FlexPrintJobScaleType.MATCH_WIDTH); // the object you want to add, and the scaling you want to apply
    printJob.send(); // Send everything to the printers.        
}
```

}

Please help with printing anychart objects. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Found the problem. Just needed to set printJob.printAsBitmap = false;